# Can I achieve this border arrow style with just one pseudo-element instead of two?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

[image: Image from GitHub]

GitHub uses two pseudoelements to show the green border around the triangle.

Like this:

[image: DOM]

Can I get the same result with only using one `::after` selector?

Comment: @dippas Is there a better duplicate than that? The question is not well worded, and the answers all refer to external sites (jsfiddle etc) and it is not specifically about a triangle with a border. This was shaping up to be higher quality, I reckon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try this**

```css
div {
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  background:#fff;
  border:1px solid green;
  position:relative;
  padding:20px;
 }
 
 div:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  right:-11px;
  top:30px;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background:#fff;
  border:1px solid green;
  border-left:none;
  border-bottom:none;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
  user-select:none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim 
  veniam,quis nostrud exercitation 
</div>
```

Comment: I checked and it's kind of 1px too far to the left in IE11. Is Github's version more consistent maybe and that's the reason they did it that way?

Answer (score 0):

You can used `:after` & `:before` selector for that

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #1db73f;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius:5px;
}
div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: 30px;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid #fff;
  z-index:1;
}
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -21px;
  top: 30px;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;      
  border-left: 20px solid #1db73f;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
  cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```